# winsock2 client return self port number

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, client, winsock2

I'm using lib winsock2 in Visual Studio community, using simple client example.
After executing connect() function, would like to know how can I get/return self/source port number of open connection.

Comment: The local port is given by `getsockname()`. The remote port is given by `getpeername()`.

Comment: function `getpeername()` didn't return ip or port data, but `getsockname()` give structed where we  find ip and port, using `ntohs()` allow u grab from struct the port

Comment: `getpeername()` does what I described. It returns a similar `struct` to `getsockname()` but relating to the peer, not the local endpoint. Unless you want to assert that a system call that has existed for 40 years doesn't work.

Comment: I understood the problem of communication between me and you.
you created the wrong construction of words and sentences.

Due to this, I got the impression that the functions you listed immediately pass the port, while they pass structural data that contains the port and other data that needs to be parsed. anyway thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you got `getsockname()` working you got `getpeername()` working too, or you should have. Your own answer says they work the same way. Nobody told you different.

Answer (score -1):

In winsock2, when a connection is established you can bind socket port to some specific port you want to use. For example, let´s say you are creating an UDP or TCP socket and you want that a specific local port is used. In that case you can do that by calling *bind* function ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind )

```
    if (port != 0) {
        int rv = -1;
        struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
        ZeroMemory(&recv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        recv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        recv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        recv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        rv = bind(udp_channel->socket, (SOCKADDR *)& recv_addr, sizeof(recv_addr));
    }
```

This is the same *bind* function you will use to set listening port when your socket will act as a server in UDP or TCP, it's the same.

In case you don't do socket binding, socket port will be assigned on connection. There seems to be the function *getsockname* that user207421 mentioned.

Comment: `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()` is for servers. OP is asking about client code.

Comment: You are right! All that part of the answer is wrong, because it doesn't apply. Thank you!

Comment: After some time i found `SO_BSP_STATE` and function `getsockopt()` , but I have problems in using it, because it always returns me some worng.
`getsockopt((SOCKET)ConnectSocket, (int)SOL_SOCKET, (int)SO_BSP_STATE, (char*)&buf_, (int*)&buf_len);` trying using after and front `Connect()` but always get bad valves

Comment: @sc20ka you did not show how `buf_` is declared, or how `buf_len` is initialized, or how you are viewing/displaying the content of `buf_` that makes you think it is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

### getsockname() or getpeername()

- returning Structured data with `short sin_family` and `char sa_data[]` with different amount of data depending on the protocols used
- after connection to server use fuction `getsockname()` or  `getpeername()` to get the structured data we need to extract the data to get the port
- you use function `ntohs()` for extracting the port data with macro function `SS_PORT` to convert struct to `sockaddr_in`

example:

```
sockaddr struc_;
int struc_len = sizeof(struc_);
/* connect function*/
getsockname(ConnectSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)&struc_, &struc_len);
int port_int_ = ntohs(SS_PORT(&struc_));
```

- or you can define a ready-made structure / create your own, with a pointer to port number data.

Comment: `getsockopt()` has nothing to do with it. You were given the answer hours ago, and the code you have posted uses it. Not `getsockopt()`.

Comment: Also, declaring `struc_` as `sockaddr` is wrong. It needs to be either `sockaddr_in` (if the socket is using `AF_INET`) or `sockaddr_in6` (if the socket is using `AF_INET6`) or `sockaddr_storage` (if the socket is dual-stack). Also, there is no need for the `SS_PORT()` macro when you can just access the `sin(6)_port` field directly.

Comment: I don't see any error here.
either we do data parsing and distribution with a predefined struct "a" or we do data parsing and data distribution with a predefined struct "b".
after which we extract data from the selected structures, but there is no difference how to do this, because everything will be the same for the compiler.

Comment: re edit answer.

Comment: There are no errors here *after* you corrected all the ones you were told about, and you were already told the whole thing several hours ago.